# Convert each <attr> title into ISO8601, separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, utc, iso8601, timeago

**Question**: How do I convert each  title individually into ISO8601

I am trying to utilize the timeago JQuery library. I populate the title with UTC string, so I have to convert the UTC attr title to ISO8601 before running the Timeago library, otherwise Safari/FF/IE show nothing.

**JQuery**

```
var dateString = $('.timeago').attr('title');
var dateConvert = new Date(dateString);
 $('.timeago').attr('title', dateConvert.toISOString());
```

---

**HTML**

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="Sun, 30 Jul 2014 15:06:00 -0500"></abbr>
<abbr class="timeago" title="Sun, 30 Jul 2014 14:45:00 -0500"></abbr>
```

---

**Results**

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2014-07-30T20:06:00.000Z">3 minutes ago</abbr>
<abbr class="timeago" title="2014-07-30T20:06:00.000Z">3 minutes ago</abbr>
```

---

**Expected Results**

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2014-07-30T20:06:00.000Z">3 minutes ago</abbr>
<abbr class="timeago" title="2014-07-30T19:45:00.000Z">24 minutes ago</abbr>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: The titles that are being converted into ISO8601 are replicating the value of the first title converted to ISO8601. Every <abbr> title will be = "2014-07-30T20:06:00.000Z"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code only is grabbing the `title` attribute of the first `.timeago` element.**

[jQuery's `attr()][1]` method *"[gets] the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or [sets] one or more attributes for every matched element"* ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)).

**Use [jQuery's `.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method** if you want to perform an action on *each* selected element in a set:

```
$(".timeago").each(function() {
    var dateString = $(this).attr('title');
    var dateConvert = new Date(dateString);
    $(this).attr('title', dateConvert.toISOString());
});
```

Comment: Thanks. My abstract structuring ability is pretty bad.

I was trying 
$('.timeago', this).attr('title', dateConvert.toISOString());

Comment: No worries! Happens to everyone (except Jon Skeet). :P